# If I obtained a username and the salted password pairs from a server, can I login?

Tags: authentication, hash, pbkdf2

I am studying Salted Challenge Response Authentication Mechanism (SCRAM).

According to the description at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5802#page-8 it seems that the Client does not have to know the password in plain text; knowing the SaltedPassword is enough to compute the ClientProof.

That would mean that if I manage to obtain the salted passwords from a database, I could log in without having to brute force the passwords.

Is my understanding of SCRAM correct in this respect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Disclaimer***: I'm no expert in cryptography so this answer come from my limited understanding of the protocol.

**Let's look at the protocol**

```
SaltedPassword  := Hi(Normalize(password), salt, i)
ClientKey       := HMAC(SaltedPassword, "Client Key")
StoredKey       := H(ClientKey)
AuthMessage     := client-first-message-bare + "," +
                    server-first-message + "," +
                    client-final-message-without-proof
ClientSignature := HMAC(StoredKey, AuthMessage)
ClientProof     := ClientKey XOR ClientSignature
ServerKey       := HMAC(SaltedPassword, "Server Key")
ServerSignature := HMAC(ServerKey, AuthMessage)
```

**Who know what at the start?**

- The server knows : salt, i, StoredKey, ServerKey
- The client knows : password
- Both parties know the AuthMessage as part of the exchange

**The answer**

You are right that only the SaltedPassword is required to compute everything but the problem is that no one stores that SaltedPassword. Also, if you want to simply impersonnate the client, you only need the ClientKey to fool the server.

**The idea behind SCRAM --> A failure?**

> The secure authentication mechanism most widely deployed and used by
>   Internet application protocols is the transmission of clear-text
>   passwords over a channel protected by Transport Layer Security (TLS).
>   There are some significant security concerns with that mechanism,
>   which could be addressed by the use of a challenge response
>   authentication mechanism protected by TLS.

Still, it doesn't seem to explain how it will protect the password from the server. You have to understand that even if you use some kind of fancy challenge response mechanism to "never" send the password over the wire, that when you enter the password on the browser page, that is served by the server, the script in the page could decide to record your password even if it tells you that it doesn't.

The main advantage, that I see, of a challenge-response mechanism for the users is that they would be able to reuse the same password everywhere. But, since the user really cannot trust the page where it enters his password, he cannot reuse his password.

Then, the next big advantage that I could think of is that in a challenge-response mechanism the password usually isn't stored on the server. So, even if an attacker stole a copy of the server, he cannot try to de-hash the password. Again, it's a big fail since the server has a copy of the StoredPassword, the salt and the iteration count. He has all he needs to try to crack your password via dictionary or bruteforce attack.

At some point, I have to wonder, why not just give the password to the server? The only protection that it adds is that if TLS is broken (but the attacker can only listen), the attacker still has to brute-force your password in order to gain access.

Comment: SCRAM's channel binding allows for TLS without CAs. Normally we need a certificate to ensure the server is who we think it is. Otherwise an attacker could pretend to be the server and intercept our password. With SCRAM, if the authentication process succeeds, the client can be sure that the server knew the password to start with and therefore the server is not an imposter. And if it was an imposter, the authentication fails and the password is not revealed.

Comment: @user7610 Thx for the info on channel binding but... I don't think SCRAM challenge response mechanism provide any protection againts MitM attack like TLS with CAs does. Does it? The MitM can only listen by forwarding message to both parties during the authentication part, but after that, he has full control to modify any message that he wants. So we got a "secure" authentication to continue with an insecure conversation.

Comment: Channel binding should stop the MitM. MitM creates two channels: from client to attacker and from attacker to the server. Client and server then each see a different channel, therefore channel binding fails.